# C programming segmentation fault for a returned pointer by a function inside another file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have this very simple code written in C. They are in two separate files.

myFunction.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *extFunc() {
    int *a = (int *) calloc( 1, sizeof(int) );
    *a = 12;
    return a;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *p = (int *) extFunc();
    int x = *p; // causes segmentation fault !
    printf("%d\n", *p); // causes segmentation fault !
}
```

I compiled it with this command `cc myFunction.c main.c` and the output is like below

```
main.c:6:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'extFunc' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int *p = (int *) extFunc();
                         ^
main.c:6:11: warning: cast to 'int *' from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        int *p = (int *) extFunc();
                 ^
2 warnings generated.
```

and when I run it, it gives `Segmentation fault: 11`. What am I doing wrong?

I checked the function when it is in the main.c file and it worked. However, I need them to be separate like above.

In my original code there are struct pointers instead of integer pointers. I explained my problem here with a simplified example.

Comment: try 
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
and then
int *p = (int *) extFunc();

Comment: The function is not declared neither defined for the compiler, see the error message. Never skip warnings, its a bad habit. Either you write the function in your main.c or you write a header file and include the header file in your main.

Comment: @jforberg the question is not about the warnings. I just added extra information of what happened when I compiled it.

Comment: @EmadGoahri Yes it is. The warnings tell you what is wrong with your code. If you had simply made a google search for "implicit declaration of function" you would have found the answer quickly.

Comment: @jforberg ok you are right. I didn't know that. should I delete this question?

Comment: @EmadGoahri No harm done. In the future, I would encourage you to spend some more time searching the site before posting a question. Any warnings you get are probably indicative of what your problem is.

Comment: I would recommend to add the option `-pedantic-errors` to GCC. Especially if you are a beginner still learning the language. This will give you an error and not just a warning, if you write something that isn't allowed in standard C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided a prototype for `extFunc()`. Create a header file with:

```
int *extFunc(void);
```

and include it in both source files.

Since the compiler can't see a prototype it assumed `int` as return type for `extFunc()` which probably truncates the address returned by `calloc()` on your system (probably 64bit system).
But there's no implicit int rule since C99. Always include prototypes for functions and pay attention to compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

The warnings are very important here. Especially the one saying

> cast to 'int *' from smaller integer type 'int'

What is happening is that the compiler makes an *implicit* declaration of the function. One that doesn't return `int *` but `int`. On certain platform (most notably 64-bit systems) those are not the same which means the pointer `p` in your `main` function is not correct. Dereferencing it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

You need to add a declaration of your function for it to work:

```
int *extFunc(void);

int main(void) { ... }
```

Also note that I have changed the argument type for both your `extFunc` and for `main`. This is because in C when you don't explicitly say that a function takes `void` as argument then it can take any number of unspecified arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling both files is not enough, you need to create a header:

```
/* myFunction.h */

int *extFunc();
```

And then, include it in your main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "myFunction.h" /* here */

int main()
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main cannot see the declaration of the function extFunc, so it's return type default to int.

As types int and int* are not of the same size, the function returns an invalid pointer, which when dereferenced caused a segmentation fault.

You will need to create a header called myFunction.h, which will contain the declaration of the function:

```
int* extFunc( void );
```

Include this header in main and also change the definition of extFunc to take no arguments in myFunction.c.